# co-ordinate system of window in opengl

Tags: opengl, graphics

how is the co-ordinate system of window in opengl?
In some programs some one coded as upper left as (0,0) but in some other coded as middle of window as (0,0).
I think normally centre as middle of window. then how will change (0,0) to upper left corner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default window coordinate sytem is

```
 (0,0) = left bottom corner(origin)
 (screen.width-1, screen.height-1) = upper right corner
```

This is the last of three different coordinate systems which represents a 3d model after 3 coordinate transfirmation as a 2d image on screen or a specified area (viewport ) on screen.

Comment: what is the maximum size of window?

Comment: The maximum size depends on your configured resolution for your screen.

Comment: @bushra: That is OS specific. One can create windows which are larger than the screen on many OS and window systems. As far as GL is concerned, there is the `GL_MAXIMUM_VIEWPORT_LIMIT` that is relevant here.

Comment: how to check what is the maximum size of window? becouse it is required for some programming codes.

Comment: This depends on the franework you use. Glut or glfw. Have a look on this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335301/glfw-get-screen-height-width

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux using EGL, you can use below to get the surface sizes.

```
eglQuerySurface(eglDisplay, eglSurface, EGL_WIDTH, &windowWidth);
eglQuerySurface(eglDisplay, eglSurface, EGL_HEIGHT, &windowHeight);
```